# access user info from Firebase.js config file to background.js service worker file not working on startup. In Chrome extension manifest version 3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a Chrome extension with a react boilerplate folder and I have set up Firebase such that a user can log in and log out using the pop-up window. I also have a firebase.js file with the configuration.

It works fine but the problem is that I want to make an API call to Firebase cloud functions in my service worker background.js script but I need to get asses to user info so currently I am trying to send a message from the firebase.js file onAuthChange to my background.ts file but this only works if the user has already opened the pop-up window during the session. If the user does not open the popup window no message is sent to the bakcgorund.js file even though Firebase saves the user info and keeps the user logged in.

Though I was wondering if I can import the auth and the onAuthStateChanged instead directly to the background.js but it does not work either. The background.ts file just does not run when I do that.

How can I solve this? I tried using the storage.local API and it worked but I don't think this is recommended, because of security reasons.

#### background.ts file

(trying to get user info on start-up and update, but I only receive it after popup.tsx has ran)

```
let currentUser;

console.log('background.js running')
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'toFirebase'}) /* it returns: Could not establish connection. Receiving  end does not exist.           suggesting that the firbase file is not running, I think */

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  if (request.type !== 'userInfoFromFirebase') return;
  currentUser = request.user;
  console.log(currentUser)  // it logs the user when the popup.tsx is pressed, but not on load/startup.

 
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if(request.type != 'selectedTextToBackground'){
    return
  }
  console.log(`current User Email ${JSON.stringify(currentUser.email)}`) 

/* if I have not opened the popup.tsx it throws Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email') */



  // console.log(currentUser)
  

 
  // chrome.storage.local.get([storageKey, 'user'], result => {
  // const userLoggedIn = result[storageKey];
```

#### firebase.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
  if (request.type !== 'toFirebase') return; 
/*just trying to see if I get get access to the firebase file through background.js*/
});

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import {getAuth, onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth'
import { storageKey } from '../popup/constants';

console.log('firebase File')

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "A...
  authDomain: "c..
  projectId:..
....
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export {app};

// Check user authentication state and store it in chrome.storage
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  if (user) {

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'userInfoFromFirebase',user: user })

  } else {

    // User is logged out
  }
});
```

###popup.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './popup.css'
import Signup from './Signup'
import Login from './Login'
import {auth} from '../static/firebase'
import {signOut} from 'firebase/auth'
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'


const Popup = () => { 
    const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false); 
    const [showSignUp, setShowSignUp] = useState(false);
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth)

    const handleLogin = ()=>{
        setShowSignUp(false)
        setShowLogin(true)
    }

    const handleSignUp = ()=>{
        setShowLogin(false)
        setShowSignUp(true)
    }

    const closeLog = ()=> {
        setShowLogin(false)
        setShowSignUp(false)
    }

    const handleLogOut = () => {
        signOut(auth).then(() => {
            // Sign-out successful.
        }).catch((error) => {
            // An error happened.
        });
    }
    


    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl text-green-500">Celerity-Ai Text Enhancer</h1>
            {user && <h2>Hello {user.email}</h2>}
    
            { !user && <button className='logButton' onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button> }
            { !user && <button className="logButton" onClick={handleSignUp}>Sign Up</button>}
            { user && <button onClick={handleLogOut} className="logButton">Log out</button>}

            {showSignUp && <Signup close={closeLog}logButton='Create Accunt' logHeading='SignUp' invert={handleLogin} invertName='Login insted ?'/>}
            {showLogin && <Login close={closeLog} logButton='Log in' logHeading='Login' invert={handleSignUp} invertName=' Dont have an account, SignUp ? '/>}


        </div>
    )
};



export default Popup;
```

#### manifest.jason

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "react-boilerplate",
    "description": "react-boilerplate for chrome extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action" : {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "React Boilerplate",
        "default_icon" : "icon.png"
    },
  
    "permissions":[
        "scripting",
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "storage"
        
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16" : "icon.png",
        "48" : "icon.png",
        "128" : "icon.png"
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js", "type": "module"
    }, 
    "web_accessible_resources":[
    {
      "resources": [
        "content.css"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
    ],
    "commands": {
        "_execute_action": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
            }
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried importing the onAuthStateChaged and the auth it self to the background.js file
but that did not ither work. I got this error:

```
background.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'chrome-extension://npapdnlnipmpcmdfbedpabjchkeaeaco/static/firebase.js' failed to load.at chrome-extension://npapdnlnipmpcmdfbedpabjchkeaeaco/background.js:1:26at chrome-extension://npapdnlnipmpcmdfbedpabjchkeaeaco/background.js:1:4346
```

background.ts (when trying to import onAuthStateChanged directly instead)

```
importScripts('../static/firebase.js'
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../static/firebase.js';

let currentUser;

// Check user authentication state and update the currentUser variable
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  if (user) {
    currentUser = user;
    console.log(currentUser);
  } else {
    currentUser = null;
    console.log('User logged out');
  }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if(request.type != 'selectedTextToBackground'){
    return
  }
  console.log(`current User Email ${JSON.stringify(currentUser.email)}`)
```